# Ho to run docker on windows 10 32 bit?

Tags: docker, windows-10, 32-bit, docker-machine

Installed docker on 32 bit windows following this blog https://medium.com/@chrispatten/installing-and-running-docker-on-32-bit-windows-d18b95ee1fc3 and docker successfully installed [image]

But when i run `docker run hello-world` it gives following error
[image]

So how can i run docker commands on windows 10 32 bit?

Answer (score 2):

The choco script doesn't work any more.

Please use the official [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) which is primarly for Windows 7 and 32bit Systems.

> Docker Toolbox provides a way to use Docker on Windows systems that do not meet minimal system requirements for the Docker for Windows app.

Comment: Docker Toolbox requires 64 bit OS to run docker